# WordPress redirect rule in nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, nginx

I have Wordpress `.htaccess` where I have written a redirect rule. It is working perfectly. But now I am hosting the site in nginx. Where I came to know, there is no `.htaccess`. So I got a file named `default` in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. In this file I have to write.

But after written the redirect rule, nothing is happened.

I have written in `.htaccess` like this

```
RewriteRule ^business/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /business-profile/?id=$1 [L,P]
```

And now written in `default` file like this:

```
# nginx configuration
location /business {
rewrite ^/business/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /business-profile/?id=$1 break;
}
```

But cant get any result. Is there anything I left ? Please help.

Answer (score -1):

```
# nginx configuration
location /business {
rewrite ^/business/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /aimber/business-profile/?id=$1 break;
}
```

I think you forgot "/aimber", the above should work.